# How to prevent uGet downloading a specific link?

Tags: google-chrome, downloads, uget

I have always been wondering how to integrate `uGetdm` with chrome under `Ubuntu 14.04`. I have finally found the way to it via [uGet Chrome Wrapper](https://slgobinath.github.io/uget-chrome-wrapper/#ubuntu).

Now, everything meant to be downloaded is passed to uGet to download it and My problem now is that if a server does not let `uGet` to download the file, and I would then have to press and hold a key to make the chrome itself do the downloading job, I don't know if it is at all possible (like with IDM in windows we press and hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key I imagine). 
Would you help me find a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the Extension from taking over the download and sending to uGet by pressing and holding <kbd>Insert</kbd> key when clicking to download.

You can also disable it for longer term by pressing Insert <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>